# Using Typekit with Meteor

Tags: meteor, typekit

I'm planning to use Typekit in a project, but I have some doubts if it works well with Meteor. 
I tried to add the script tags to the head of the main.html, but it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/xxxxxx.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That should work — I have a few sites built with Meteor where I use typekit successfully.

You should check the console.log to see if there's any error. Typeki's kits only work on  domain names specified for that particular kit, so perhaps you've specified "localhost" but are browsing to 127.0.0.1 — or something like that.

Comment: have you tested using **Typekit** with the **browser-policy** package? http://docs.meteor.com/#browserpolicy (thanks)